# Add the lang-mumps module from Prettify

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

As of late, I have been writing [a number of answers on CodeGolf.SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8890/senshin?tab=answers), using MUMPS (or a close variant) as my language of choice. MUMPS tends to look remarkably like line noise, whether or not you're trying to golf it. Some syntax highlighting sure would help.

Luckily! The main Prettify repository already has [a module for MUMPS](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/src/lang-mumps.js). I have used it myself, and can verify that it generally works.

Can we add that module to the SE version of prettify.js? (Perhaps only on CodeGolf if it turns out that adding more Javascript to the bigger programming sites like SO would cause an unacceptable increase in load time? There are only [45 [mumps] questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new/mumps) on SO right now, so I understand that the extra cost of loading another prettify module might not be worthwhile there. And I doubt there's any MUMPS anywhere on the network besides SO and CodeGolf.)

Comment: +1 if only so that I can say that I voted in favor of something supporting MUMPS.  Codegolfing is bad enough.  Codegolfing in MUMPS simply takes it to a new level.